# control of the version of iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, version

guys. Now I am developing an app in Xcode 7 beta4 and I have a question about the version of the app. How I can know this app can only be run in a system over iOS 9.0 or 8.0 ? Can i set this in Xcode or somewhere? Can you guys help me? Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is int the project settings. That is kind of 'global' setting.

[image]

But it can be overwritten in settings for the target.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you. Now i have another question. If I set the deployment target to be 7.1, so it means this app can only be run in the system of  ios 7.1 or higher, right?  But I used some new framworks from ios 9, so the iphone with  ios 8.0 can run my app or not?  Thank you again!

Comment: I guess you are asking me if it's possible to travel back in time ;) If you are using some API/framework that is for iOS 9 then when you run this code on pre 9 iOS you application will crash. You have to check in code is that API available for you and use it only then :)  Here is a [google search](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=support+multiple+version+of+ios) to get you started on the topic :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Xcode you set Deployment Target in Project->Build Settings.